# BigInteger.TryParse works locally but not on Azure VM

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core

I have a code that looks like this:

```
var trimmedValue = value.Replace(" ", "");
var style = NumberStyles.Any;

if (BigInteger.TryParse(value, style, null, out BigInteger number))
{
    // Run code
}

return new ValidationResult { Error = "Could not validate " + value + " as int." };
```

This works for me locally and it validates the BigInteger. On Azure the `.TryParse` returns false running the same value. Anyone got an idea why this is not working for me on Azure? I'm pretty new to C# so I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: What value are you trying to use? Could be related to locale, as that could be different on the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `null` argument with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or whatever culture you are using locally:

```
if (BigInteger.TryParse(value, style, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out BigInteger number))
...
```

For example, if your local culture is fr-FR, you could use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")` instead of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.